# Get first date using FIRSTDATE or MIN function in DAX

Tags: dax

I've trid to get the first date from 'Date' column with below 2 DAX "MEASURE"s

1. firstDate = FIRSTDATE('Table 1'[Date])
2. minDate = min([Date])

But I didn't get the right results in the table visuals.
You can find all "firstData" and "minDate" are same with values in "Date" column

How to get the first data which shoud be "19-01-14" using DAX measures?

Many Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with the help of someone else as below

calculate(min(table1[date]),all(table1))

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/DAX-Commands-and-Tips/Get-first-date-using-FIRSTDATE-or-MIN-funciton/td-p/1679359#M34452